# Como trocar uma string com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu preciso capturar uma string, pegar um pedaço dela e trocar este pedaço por outro texto.

```
<img src="/kit_150x150-12por-150x150.png">
```

Preciso pegar o pedaço `150x150.png` do `src` e trocar por ***238x238.png*** com ***jQuery***. Eu consigo acessar o atributo mais a partir daí não consigo pegar um pedaço e trocar o valor do texto.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Não muda não, por isso coloquei o .png em seguida na pergunta !!!

Answer (score 4):

Se os valores forem estáticos você pode trocar diretamente:

```
var src = "/kit_150x150-12por-150x150.png";
var src = src.replace("150x150.png", "238x238.png");
```

ou dinamicamente usando uma regex (teste-a neste [link](https://regex101.com/), funciona com o seu exemplo):

```
/[0-9]+[x|X][0-9]+.png/
```

Referenciando uma resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string) que pode ajuda-lo a ligar as strings: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string)

Answer (score 4):

Similar a do @Ricardo só que em função.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<img id="imgRotate" src="/kit_150x150-12por-238x238.png">

<script>
function changeImg(id, size){
    var src = jQuery('#'+id).attr('src');
    var src = src.replace(/\d+x\d+\.png/, size);
    jQuery('#'+id).attr('src', src);
}
changeImg('imgRotate', '266x266.png');
</script>
```